# Applying NumberFormat Date to entire column where header equals "Date" in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I wanted to Apply a TableStyle to an imported Table, but apparently a TableStyle can't overwrite currently existing Formats. But when I use .ClearFormats, it will also Clear the NumberFormat for the "Date" column.

So I decided to do a workaround and use .ClearFormats, but re-apply the Date NumberFormat afterwards. The only problem I am facing is the fact that there are rows with an empty cell in the "Date" column, which makes me unable to use .End(xlDown).

So over to the question:
How can I select a Range/Selection where the header name equals "Date" and apply the NumberFormat "dd-mm-yyyy" to the entire column. (PS. I can't hardcode the column number, because the Date might be in a different column for the next imported sheet.)

Comment: If you use Table feature, you can use `ListObject(index).ListColumns(index)` to refer to the column. Or you can use `.End(xlUp)` from the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
colDate = Application.Match("Date", Rows(1), 0) '<-- Assuming your header is at row 1
Columns(colDate).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

The first statement fetches the label "Date" in the header row. The second sets a Date format to the used part of that column.

Comment: @YowE3K I removed all what relates to usedRange, in fact I realized it doesn't make sense. The goal is to format all the column (to apply for new values) and also, OP will have to apply it on the actual row of the header i n his worksheet. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot and happy holidays!

Comment: @DavyHeutmekers You are welcome mate, I wish you the same :)

Answer (score 0):

to strictly answer your question:

```
With Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| change "1" to your actual header row index
    .Parent.Range(.Cells, .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.count, .Column).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End With
```

while if you don't want to rely on `ActiveSheet`:

```
With Worksheets("myTableWorksheetName").Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| change "myTableWorksheetName" to your actual sheet name and "1" to your actual header row index
    .Parent.Range(.Cells, .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.count, .Column).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End With
```